# Index out of bounds in Quiz program

Tags: java

I'm making a quiz program that calls two .txt files (one at a time) to get questions and answers. The two files have different numbers of questions and answers. It goes through them in order and after you get the answer to the last question and hit the get question button, it gives an index out of bounds error. I'm trying to figure out the best way to get the jbuttonQ to be disabled after the last question has been displayed. I think I'm missing a for loop or a try catch somewhere. The questions and answers are separate ArrayList

Here's the jbuttonQ action performed code:

```
 statusMessageLabel.setText("");
 jtxtA.setText("");
 jtxtQ.setText(q.getQuestion());
 jtxtCurrQ.setText(String.valueOf(q.getQNumber()));
 jbtnA.setEnabled(true);
 jbtnA.requestFocusInWindow();
 jbtnQ.setEnabled(false);
```

Here's the jbuttonA action performed code:

```
statusMessageLabel.setText("");
    jtxtA.setText(q.getAnswer());
    jbtnQ.setEnabled(true);
    jbtnQ.requestFocusInWindow();
    jbtnA.setEnabled(false);
```

Here's the jbtnMenu code:

```
statusMessageLabel.setText("");
    jtxtQ.setText("");
    jtxtA.setText("");
    jtxtCurrQ.setText("");
    jtxtTotQ.setText("");
    JFileChooser f = new JFileChooser(".");
    String path = "";
    f.setDialogTitle("Select quiz file.");
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Text file (*.txt)","txt");
    f.setFileFilter(filter);
    JDialog dg = new JDialog();
    int rval = f.showOpenDialog(dg);
    if(rval == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION){
        statusMessageLabel.setText("Open canceled.");
        jtxtFile.setText("");
    }else{
        path = f.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        jtxtFile.setText(path);
        q = new Quiz(path); //instantiation call
        if(q.getErrorMsg().isEmpty()){
            statusMessageLabel.setText(q.getActionMsg());
            jtxtTotQ.setText(String.valueOf(q.getQCount()));
            jbtnQ.setEnabled(true);
            jbtnQ.requestFocusInWindow();
        }else{
            statusMessageLabel.setText(q.getErrorMsg());
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the  Quiz.java class:

```
public class Quiz {
private String filename;
private String errmsg, actmsg;
private ArrayList<String> questions;
private ArrayList<String> answers;
private int qCount, qNumber;
private boolean quizover;

public Quiz(String path){
    this.errmsg = "";
    this.actmsg = "";
    questions = new ArrayList<>();
    answers = new ArrayList<>();

    try{
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
        String s = in.readLine();
        while (s != null){
            questions.add(s);
            answers.add(in.readLine());
            qCount++;
            s = in.readLine();
        }
        in.close();

    }catch(IOException e){
        this.errmsg = "Unable to open file " + path;
    }
    if (qCount > 0){
        this.actmsg = "Quiz file has " + qCount + " questions.";
        qNumber = 1;
        quizover = false;
    }else if(qCount <= 0){
        this.actmsg = "No questions in file: " + path;
        qNumber = 0;
        quizover = true;
     }
}//end of constructor
public String getErrorMsg(){
    return this.errmsg;
}
public String getActionMsg(){
    return this.actmsg;
}
public int getQCount(){
    return this.qCount;
}
public int getQNumber(){
    return this.qNumber;
}
public String getQuestion(){

    if(this.qCount == 0){
        this.errmsg = "Question requested from empty quiz.";
        return this.errmsg;
    }


    return this.questions.get(this.qNumber - 1);
}
public String getAnswer(){
    if(this.qCount == 0){
        this.errmsg = "Answer requested from empty quiz.";
        return this.errmsg;
    }
    String a = this.answers.get(this.qNumber - 1);
    qNumber ++;
    return a;
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "The two files have different numbers of questions and answers" Does this mean that the question and answer files have different numbers of entries, or that the files can contain any number, as long as the two files have equal numbers?

Comment: ... and which line is getting the IndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: The two files have different numbers of entries. It doesn't say which line, it says "Exception in thread AWT-EventQueue-0 Index out of bounds exception: Index 6, size 6

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have not shared your complete code; so, my understanding of your code at this point is limited.

But, the biggest problem is that you are checking for 'the last question' with this.qCount but your get is with this.qNumber; also you need to decrement qNumber. Try with something like this:

```
public String getQuestion(){

    if (this.qNumber > 0) {
        return this.questions.get(this.qNumber - 1);
    }
    else {
        this.errmsg = "Question requested from empty quiz.";
        return this.errmsg;
    }
}

public String getAnswer(){

    if (this.qNumber > 0) {
        String a = this.answers.get(this.qNumber - 1);
        qNumber--;
        return a;
    }
    else {
        this.errmsg = "Answer requested from empty quiz.";
        return this.errmsg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I changed the jbtnA code:

```
 statusMessageLabel.setText("");
    if(String.valueOf(q.getQNumber()).equals(String.valueOf(q.getQCount()))){
        statusMessageLabel.setText("End of questions in file.");
        jbtnQ.setEnabled(false);
    }else{
    jtxtA.setText(q.getAnswer());
    jbtnQ.setEnabled(true);
    jbtnQ.requestFocusInWindow();
    jbtnA.setEnabled(false);
    }
```